# Excel VBA gPdDoc.open(path) failed

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am writing a vba code to match strings in excel to pdf. The reason i am doing it is because i got an excel sheet which someone summarised and complied information from over a hundred pdf together. I want to double check if the information is placed in the correct cell, for example, if PDF1's information is in PDF1's row. and maybe later i'll use the code to auto search and find texts in pdf.

Yet, I stuck with open the pdf. gPdDoc.open (path) does not work. My code is as below.

```
Sub FindText()

Dim gApp As Object, gPdDoc As Object

Set PdfAPP = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set gPdDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

texttofind = "something I want to find"
filepath = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Switzerland"

   If gPdDoc.Open(filepath, "") Then
            foundtext=gPdDoc.findtext(texttofind)
       Else
            MsgBox ("Failed to open " & Path)
   End If


End Sub
```

when run code *gPdDoc.Open(Path, "")*, Acrobat opens but a pop-up window says like "error when open the file, can't find the file". I'm pretty sure the filepath is correct, and i can open the file with Acrobat directly (double click). It's really confusing why the file is not found when i try to open it in Acrobat via VBA.

I'd really love to know how to make it work. and even better if anyone knows easier ways to auto search texts in multiple PDFs.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how you are even managing to get `gPdDoc.Open(filepath, "') Then` to compile ?!?!  There doesn't appear to be a closing double-quote character, and therefore no closing bracket, and therefore no "Then".

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the filepath should be filepath = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Switzerland.pdf"

the path needs to end with ".pdf"